# How to we move current applied filter state to center of the page just beside the sortby

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, multiple-select-layered

In the category page layered navigation, I want to move the current applied filter state just beside the sort by or center of the page.

Can anyone please help me out?
[image]

Comment: it might help to provide a screenshot or mock up of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @paj updated the ticket please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html elements for the selected filters you will see they are an ordered list.

```
<ol class="items">
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
</ol>
```

Assuming your `block-content filter-content` column is wide enough to arrange the list items horizontally instead of vertically then you can do this by overriding the css for the list items `<li>` to

```
.filter .filter-content .item {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will let u know. Thanks